# Does Kotlin has extension class to interface like Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Swift, we could extend a class with an interface as below

```
extension MyExtend {
   public var type: String { return "" }
}

extension MyOrigin: MyExtend {
   public var type: ListItemDataType {
       return "Origin"
   }
}
```

Do we have that capability in Kotlin? (e.g. extend an interface)

Comment: check this http://nilhcem.com/swift-is-like-kotlin/

Comment: From http://nilhcem.com/swift-is-like-kotlin/, it doesn't shows one could extends from the extension. Sounds like we don' have this in Kotlin.

Comment: No, kotlin doesn't.

Comment: Not yet possible.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, **Kotlin** does have [`Extensions`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) — similar to **Swift**.

**Swift**:

```
class C {
    func foo(i: String) { print("class") }
}

extension C {
    func foo(i: Int) { print("extension") }
}

C().foo(i: "A")
C().foo(i: 1)
```

**Kotlin**:

```
class C {
    fun foo(i: String) { println("class") }
}

fun C.foo(i: Int) { println("extension") }

C().foo("A")
C().foo(1)
```

**Output**:

```
class
extension
```

There are some key differences you'll want to read up on.

> Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend. By defining an
>   extension, you do not insert new members into a class, but merely make
>   new functions callable with the dot-notation on variables of this
>   type.
>
> We would like to emphasize that extension functions are dispatched
>   statically, i.e. they are not virtual by receiver type. This means
>   that the extension function being called is determined by the type of
>   the expression on which the function is invoked, not by the type of
>   the result of evaluating that expression at runtime.

↳ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Comment: Thanks. Your example given is Extension of function. What I'm hoping to achieve is to extension to an interface, so that it would need to implement all the functions within the interface. Is that something possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Currently extension functions and extension properties are only supported, in the future there will likely be additions that include that ability.

Comment: That's really nice to know. Looking forward to that.

Comment: @I'L'l Curious where your information on "there will likely be additions" comes from. I'm a Kotlin contributor and I'm not aware of any plans to add that.

Comment: @yole: The source was from a Kotlin presentation some time ago, "[Kotlin for the Pragmatic Functionalist](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/kotlinconf2017/slides/PacoEstevez_Pragmatic_Functionalism.pdf)" (hosted on JetBrains). At the time it seemed as though you guys were "*aiming for parity with Swift protocols*", however, I suspect from your comment *likely* is not the right word?

Comment: Kotlin extensions are too far from powerful swift ones. Inability to access private properties of extensible class makes kotlin extensions useless