# Can i make extensions in Kotlin as in Swift

Tags: android, swift, kotlin

Is there any way to make extension of any type in Kotlin like String, Int, Double etc.

Lets say this example in Swift:

```
extension Int {
    func squared() -> Int {
        return self * self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var number = 8
print(number.squared())
//Prints 64
```

Can be formatted for Kotlin?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362347/does-kotlin-has-extension-class-to-interface-like-swift) couldn't help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50362347/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod I saw this question before I ask and I couldn't understand how I could do mine, so I believe as new in kotlin this question will help many like me and As it isn't ask the same thing it isn't duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Kotlin allows the use of [Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

```
fun Int.squared(): Int{
    // Your code
    // use `this` parameter to get int value
    // return value
}
```

and the use it anywhere like this:

```
val squared = 3.squared()
```

> Import statement will be automatically included if you are trying to
>   use an extension

Answer (score 1):

Extension function:

```
Integer.squared() : Int{
   return this*this
}
```

Usage:

```
val squared = 3.squared()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have to accept Rahul answer though as he answered first

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Kotlin you would do it like this

```
fun Int.squared() : Int = this * this
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have to accept Rahul answer though as he answered first